WinSCP 'synchronize' - keeps copying the same files?
I'm using WinSCP (v6.3.4) to sync a folder on Windows Server 2019 with a remote server (GoAnywhere running on Centos 7.2).
When I sync a folder my assumption is that the remote now matches the local exactly.  So, if I run another 'synchronize' it'll do nothing.  Instead WinSCP seems to upload all the files again.  I'd like it to do nothing - thus telling me that the two folders are in sync.
How do I configure WinSCP so it'll only copy files if they really are changed?
I'm using the UI but am happy to use command line.
My 'Synchronize' options are:


Log file with two syncs, one at 14:19 and one at 14:20. The sync only had one file in it (myfile.txt), which was unchanged between syncs.  Basically I just ran 'Synchronize' twice in succession.
. 2024-07-26 14:19:42.964 Collecting synchronization list for local directory 'E:\testfolder' and remote directory '/testfolder', mode = Remote, params = 0x3443 (Delete, NoConfirmation, *PreviewChanges, BySize, CaseSensitive, Mirror), file mask = ''
. 2024-07-26 14:19:42.996 Local file 'E:\testfolder\.' [2024-07-25T07:25:41.152Z] [0] excluded from synchronization
. 2024-07-26 14:19:42.996 Local file 'E:\testfolder\..' [2024-07-25T07:25:41.152Z] [0] excluded from synchronization
. 2024-07-26 14:19:42.996 Local file 'E:\testfolder\myfile.txt' [2024-02-16T17:05:40.581Z] [154639] included to synchronization
. 2024-07-26 14:19:42.996 Listing directory "/testfolder".
> 2024-07-26 14:19:42.996 Type: SSH_FXP_OPENDIR, Size: 35, Number: 114776843
< 2024-07-26 14:19:42.996 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 40, Number: 114776580
. 2024-07-26 14:19:42.996 Discarding reserved response
< 2024-07-26 14:19:43.196 Type: SSH_FXP_HANDLE, Size: 45, Number: 114776843
> 2024-07-26 14:19:43.196 Type: SSH_FXP_READDIR, Size: 45, Number: 114777100
< 2024-07-26 14:19:43.382 Type: SSH_FXP_NAME, Size: 61, Number: 114777100
> 2024-07-26 14:19:43.382 Type: SSH_FXP_READDIR, Size: 45, Number: 114777356
< 2024-07-26 14:19:43.582 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 40, Number: 114777356
< 2024-07-26 14:19:43.582 Status code: 1
> 2024-07-26 14:19:43.582 Type: SSH_FXP_CLOSE, Size: 45, Number: 114777604
. 2024-07-26 14:19:43.582 myfile.txt;-;154639;2024-07-26T13:21:24.000Z;4;"" [0];"" [0];rwxrwxrwx;1
. 2024-07-26 14:19:43.582 ..;D;0;1899-12-30T00:00:00.000Z;0;"" [0];"" [0];---------;0
. 2024-07-26 14:19:43.582 Local file 'E:\testfolder\myfile.txt' [2024-02-16T17:05:40.581Z] [154639] is modified comparing to remote file '/testfolder/myfile.txt' [2024-07-26T13:21:24.000Z] [154639]
. 2024-07-26 14:19:50.363 Synchronizing local directory 'E:\testfolder\' with remote directory '/testfolder/', params = 0x3443 (Delete, NoConfirmation, *PreviewChanges, BySize, CaseSensitive, Mirror)
. 2024-07-26 14:19:50.373 Copying 1 files/directories to remote directory "/testfolder/" - total size: 154,639
. 2024-07-26 14:19:50.373   PrTime: Yes+Dirs; PrRO: No; Rght: rw-r--r--; PrR: No (No); FnCs: N; RIC: 0100; Resume: S (102400); CalcS: No; Mask: *.*
. 2024-07-26 14:19:50.373   TM: B; ClAr: No; RemEOF: No; RemBOM: No; CPS: 0; NewerOnly: No; EncryptNewFiles: Yes; ExcludeHiddenFiles: No; ExcludeEmptyDirectories: No; InclM: ; ResumeL: 0
. 2024-07-26 14:19:50.373   AscM: *.*html; *.htm; *.txt; *.php; *.php3; *.cgi; *.c; *.cpp; *.h; *.pas; *.bas; *.tex; *.pl; *.js; .htaccess; *.xtml; *.css; *.cfg; *.ini; *.sh; *.xml
. 2024-07-26 14:19:50.373 File: 'E:\testfolder\myfile.txt' [2024-02-16T17:05:40.581Z] [154639]
. 2024-07-26 14:19:50.373 Copying "E:\testfolder\myfile.txt" to remote directory started.
. 2024-07-26 14:19:50.373 Binary transfer mode selected.
. 2024-07-26 14:19:50.373 Checking existence of file.
> 2024-07-26 14:19:50.373 Type: SSH_FXP_LSTAT, Size: 55, Number: 114777863
< 2024-07-26 14:19:50.373 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 40, Number: 114777604
. 2024-07-26 14:19:50.373 Discarding reserved response
< 2024-07-26 14:19:53.175 Type: SSH_FXP_ATTRS, Size: 38, Number: 114777863
. 2024-07-26 14:19:53.175 File exists: myfile.txt;-;154639;2024-07-26T13:21:24.000Z;4;"" [0];"" [0];rwxrwxrwx;1
. 2024-07-26 14:19:53.175 Checking existence of partially transferred file.
> 2024-07-26 14:19:53.175 Type: SSH_FXP_LSTAT, Size: 64, Number: 114778119
< 2024-07-26 14:19:53.375 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 93, Number: 114778119
< 2024-07-26 14:19:53.375 Status code: 2
. 2024-07-26 14:19:53.375 Opening remote file.
> 2024-07-26 14:19:53.375 Type: SSH_FXP_OPEN, Size: 77, Number: 114778371
< 2024-07-26 14:19:53.560 Type: SSH_FXP_HANDLE, Size: 45, Number: 114778371
> 2024-07-26 14:19:53.560 Type: SSH_FXP_WRITE, Size: 32825, Number: 114778886
. 2024-07-26 14:19:53.560 Skipped 4 SSH_FXP_WRITE packets
> 2024-07-26 14:19:53.560 Type: SSH_FXP_CLOSE, Size: 45, Number: 114780164
< 2024-07-26 14:19:56.093 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 49, Number: 114778886
< 2024-07-26 14:19:56.093 Status code: 0
. 2024-07-26 14:19:58.170 Skipped 4 SSH_FXP_STATUS packets
< 2024-07-26 14:19:58.170 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 40, Number: 114780164
< 2024-07-26 14:19:58.170 Status code: 0
> 2024-07-26 14:19:58.170 Type: SSH_FXP_REMOVE, Size: 51, Number: 114780429
< 2024-07-26 14:19:58.386 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 37, Number: 114780429
< 2024-07-26 14:19:58.386 Status code: 0
> 2024-07-26 14:19:58.386 Type: SSH_FXP_RENAME, Size: 106, Number: 114780690
< 2024-07-26 14:19:58.571 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 37, Number: 114780690
< 2024-07-26 14:19:58.571 Status code: 0
. 2024-07-26 14:19:58.571 Preserving timestamp [2024-02-16T17:05:40.000Z]
> 2024-07-26 14:19:58.571 Type: SSH_FXP_SETSTAT, Size: 68, Number: 114778633
< 2024-07-26 14:19:58.772 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 40, Number: 114778633
< 2024-07-26 14:19:58.772 Status code: 0
. 2024-07-26 14:19:58.772 Transfer done: 'E:\testfolder\myfile.txt' => '/testfolder/myfile.txt' [154639]
. 2024-07-26 14:19:58.772 Copying finished: Transferred: 154,639, Elapsed: 0:00:08, CPS: 18,389/s
. 2024-07-26 14:19:58.772 Listing directory "/testfolder".
> 2024-07-26 14:19:58.772 Type: SSH_FXP_OPENDIR, Size: 35, Number: 114780939
< 2024-07-26 14:19:58.972 Type: SSH_FXP_HANDLE, Size: 45, Number: 114780939
> 2024-07-26 14:19:58.972 Type: SSH_FXP_READDIR, Size: 45, Number: 114781196
< 2024-07-26 14:19:59.167 Type: SSH_FXP_NAME, Size: 61, Number: 114781196
> 2024-07-26 14:19:59.167 Type: SSH_FXP_READDIR, Size: 45, Number: 114781452
< 2024-07-26 14:19:59.367 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 40, Number: 114781452
< 2024-07-26 14:19:59.367 Status code: 1
> 2024-07-26 14:19:59.367 Type: SSH_FXP_CLOSE, Size: 45, Number: 114781700
. 2024-07-26 14:19:59.367 myfile.txt;-;154639;2024-07-26T13:22:22.000Z;4;"" [0];"" [0];rwxrwxrwx;1
. 2024-07-26 14:19:59.367 ..;D;0;1899-12-30T00:00:00.000Z;0;"" [0];"" [0];---------;0
. 2024-07-26 14:20:40.379 Collecting synchronization list for local directory 'E:\testfolder' and remote directory '/testfolder', mode = Remote, params = 0x3443 (Delete, NoConfirmation, *PreviewChanges, BySize, CaseSensitive, Mirror), file mask = ''
. 2024-07-26 14:20:40.394 Local file 'E:\testfolder\.' [2024-07-25T07:25:41.152Z] [0] excluded from synchronization
. 2024-07-26 14:20:40.394 Local file 'E:\testfolder\..' [2024-07-25T07:25:41.152Z] [0] excluded from synchronization
. 2024-07-26 14:20:40.394 Local file 'E:\testfolder\myfile.txt' [2024-02-16T17:05:40.581Z] [154639] included to synchronization
. 2024-07-26 14:20:40.394 Listing directory "/testfolder".
> 2024-07-26 14:20:40.394 Type: SSH_FXP_OPENDIR, Size: 35, Number: 114781963
< 2024-07-26 14:20:40.394 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 40, Number: 114781700
. 2024-07-26 14:20:40.394 Discarding reserved response
< 2024-07-26 14:20:40.594 Type: SSH_FXP_HANDLE, Size: 45, Number: 114781963
> 2024-07-26 14:20:40.594 Type: SSH_FXP_READDIR, Size: 45, Number: 114782220
< 2024-07-26 14:20:40.779 Type: SSH_FXP_NAME, Size: 61, Number: 114782220
> 2024-07-26 14:20:40.779 Type: SSH_FXP_READDIR, Size: 45, Number: 114782476
< 2024-07-26 14:20:40.988 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 40, Number: 114782476
< 2024-07-26 14:20:40.988 Status code: 1
> 2024-07-26 14:20:40.988 Type: SSH_FXP_CLOSE, Size: 45, Number: 114782724
. 2024-07-26 14:20:40.988 myfile.txt;-;154639;2024-07-26T13:22:22.000Z;4;"" [0];"" [0];rwxrwxrwx;1
. 2024-07-26 14:20:40.988 ..;D;0;1899-12-30T00:00:00.000Z;0;"" [0];"" [0];---------;0
. 2024-07-26 14:20:40.988 Local file 'E:\testfolder\myfile.txt' [2024-02-16T17:05:40.581Z] [154639] is modified comparing to remote file '/testfolder/myfile.txt' [2024-07-26T13:22:22.000Z] [154639]
. 2024-07-26 14:20:43.462 Synchronizing local directory 'E:\testfolder\' with remote directory '/testfolder/', params = 0x3443 (Delete, NoConfirmation, *PreviewChanges, BySize, CaseSensitive, Mirror)
. 2024-07-26 14:20:43.482 Copying 1 files/directories to remote directory "/testfolder/" - total size: 154,639
. 2024-07-26 14:20:43.482   PrTime: Yes+Dirs; PrRO: No; Rght: rw-r--r--; PrR: No (No); FnCs: N; RIC: 0100; Resume: S (102400); CalcS: No; Mask: *.*
. 2024-07-26 14:20:43.482   TM: B; ClAr: No; RemEOF: No; RemBOM: No; CPS: 0; NewerOnly: No; EncryptNewFiles: Yes; ExcludeHiddenFiles: No; ExcludeEmptyDirectories: No; InclM: ; ResumeL: 0
. 2024-07-26 14:20:43.482   AscM: *.*html; *.htm; *.txt; *.php; *.php3; *.cgi; *.c; *.cpp; *.h; *.pas; *.bas; *.tex; *.pl; *.js; .htaccess; *.xtml; *.css; *.cfg; *.ini; *.sh; *.xml
. 2024-07-26 14:20:43.482 File: 'E:\testfolder\myfile.txt' [2024-02-16T17:05:40.581Z] [154639]
. 2024-07-26 14:20:43.482 Copying "E:\testfolder\myfile.txt" to remote directory started.
. 2024-07-26 14:20:43.482 Binary transfer mode selected.
. 2024-07-26 14:20:43.482 Checking existence of file.
> 2024-07-26 14:20:43.482 Type: SSH_FXP_LSTAT, Size: 55, Number: 114782983
< 2024-07-26 14:20:43.482 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 40, Number: 114782724
. 2024-07-26 14:20:43.482 Discarding reserved response
< 2024-07-26 14:20:43.673 Type: SSH_FXP_ATTRS, Size: 38, Number: 114782983
. 2024-07-26 14:20:43.673 File exists: myfile.txt;-;154639;2024-07-26T13:22:22.000Z;4;"" [0];"" [0];rwxrwxrwx;1
. 2024-07-26 14:20:43.673 Checking existence of partially transferred file.
> 2024-07-26 14:20:43.673 Type: SSH_FXP_LSTAT, Size: 64, Number: 114783239
< 2024-07-26 14:20:43.873 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 93, Number: 114783239
< 2024-07-26 14:20:43.873 Status code: 2
. 2024-07-26 14:20:43.873 Opening remote file.
> 2024-07-26 14:20:43.873 Type: SSH_FXP_OPEN, Size: 77, Number: 114783491
< 2024-07-26 14:20:44.088 Type: SSH_FXP_HANDLE, Size: 45, Number: 114783491
> 2024-07-26 14:20:44.088 Type: SSH_FXP_WRITE, Size: 32825, Number: 114784006
. 2024-07-26 14:20:44.088 Skipped 4 SSH_FXP_WRITE packets
> 2024-07-26 14:20:44.088 Type: SSH_FXP_CLOSE, Size: 45, Number: 114785284
< 2024-07-26 14:20:44.326 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 49, Number: 114784006
< 2024-07-26 14:20:44.326 Status code: 0
. 2024-07-26 14:20:44.358 Skipped 4 SSH_FXP_STATUS packets
< 2024-07-26 14:20:44.358 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 40, Number: 114785284
< 2024-07-26 14:20:44.358 Status code: 0
> 2024-07-26 14:20:44.358 Type: SSH_FXP_REMOVE, Size: 51, Number: 114785549
< 2024-07-26 14:20:44.562 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 37, Number: 114785549
< 2024-07-26 14:20:44.562 Status code: 0
> 2024-07-26 14:20:44.562 Type: SSH_FXP_RENAME, Size: 106, Number: 114785810
< 2024-07-26 14:20:44.762 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 37, Number: 114785810
< 2024-07-26 14:20:44.762 Status code: 0
. 2024-07-26 14:20:44.762 Preserving timestamp [2024-02-16T17:05:40.000Z]
> 2024-07-26 14:20:44.762 Type: SSH_FXP_SETSTAT, Size: 68, Number: 114783753
< 2024-07-26 14:20:44.956 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 40, Number: 114783753
< 2024-07-26 14:20:44.956 Status code: 0
. 2024-07-26 14:20:44.956 Transfer done: 'E:\testfolder\myfile.txt' => '/testfolder/myfile.txt' [154639]
. 2024-07-26 14:20:44.956 Copying finished: Transferred: 154,639, Elapsed: 0:00:01, CPS: 103,506/s
. 2024-07-26 14:20:44.956 Listing directory "/testfolder".
> 2024-07-26 14:20:44.956 Type: SSH_FXP_OPENDIR, Size: 35, Number: 114786059
< 2024-07-26 14:20:45.141 Type: SSH_FXP_HANDLE, Size: 45, Number: 114786059
> 2024-07-26 14:20:45.141 Type: SSH_FXP_READDIR, Size: 45, Number: 114786316
< 2024-07-26 14:20:45.341 Type: SSH_FXP_NAME, Size: 61, Number: 114786316
> 2024-07-26 14:20:45.341 Type: SSH_FXP_READDIR, Size: 45, Number: 114786572
< 2024-07-26 14:20:45.547 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 40, Number: 114786572
< 2024-07-26 14:20:45.547 Status code: 1
> 2024-07-26 14:20:45.547 Type: SSH_FXP_CLOSE, Size: 45, Number: 114786820
. 2024-07-26 14:20:45.547 myfile.txt;-;154639;2024-07-26T13:23:08.000Z;4;"" [0];"" [0];rwxrwxrwx;1
. 2024-07-26 14:20:45.547 ..;D;0;1899-12-30T00:00:00.000Z;0;"" [0];"" [0];---------;0


It seems that the server completely ignores the timestamp that WinSCP attempts to set upon the synchronized file:
. 2024-07-26 14:19:58.571 Preserving timestamp [2024-02-16T17:05:40.000Z]

. 2024-07-26 14:19:59.367 myfile.txt;-;154639;2024-07-26T13:22:22.000Z;4;"" [0];"" [0];rwxrwxrwx;1

So on the next synchronization run, the remote file is seen as old.
It is most likely limitation (or configuration) of the SFTP server. Please talk to its administrator or provider.
